# How to get following users post feed that has visibility condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, subquery

I am trying to make an SQL query on postgresql database that should give me posts feed of my posts and posts of users that I follow and my friends ( which is mutual follow ) I have this table structure

```
users table
id  username
1   me
2   user2
3   user3
4   user4
```

```
relationships table
id follower_id following_id
1   1           2 // me following user2
2   2           1 // user2 also following me so we are friends
3   3           1
```

```
posts table
id user_id post visibility
1   2      post1  friends
2   2      post2  public
3   2      post3  public
4   1      post4  public
5   3      post5  public
```

```
select p.*
from posts p
where (
    visibility = 'friends' and 
    user_id in (select following_id from relationships r1 where r1.follower_id = 1) and
    user_id in (select follower_id from relationships r2 where r2.following_id = 1)
) or (
    visibility = 'public' and 
    user_id in (select following_id from relationships r3 where follower_id = 1)
)
```

and this is the query I made which is giving a result but for me it is not an efficient query I need a better query to get the result as

user id 1's feed should be

```
id user_id post   visibility
1   2      post1  friends
2   2      post2  public
3   2      post3  public
4   1      post4  public
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look next query:

```
select p.*
from posts p
join (
    -- get followers and friends
    select distinct relationships.*, coalesce(friends.follower_id, 0) as friend_id
    from relationships
    -- join self for check is follower friend
    left join relationships friends on 
        relationships.following_id = friends.follower_id and
        relationships.follower_id = friends.following_id
    where relationships.follower_id = 1
) followers on (
    visibility = 'friends' and followers.friend_id = p.user_id or
    visibility = 'public' and followers.following_id = p.user_id 
);
```

Try this query on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1cdba490116dcc9271bd31b8af8c7171&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Comment: I think I should have mentioned i am using postgresql and it does not have ifnull function and when we compare this query with mine which one you think more efficient?

Comment: OK. Fixed by change `IFNULL` to `COALESCE`. Try here https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1cdba490116dcc9271bd31b8af8c7171&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12

Comment: but I think the query has problems even if I change the user to 3 it still gives me same result even tho user 3 not following user 2

Comment: oh no you are right it gives correct list I changed the user in other query my mistake. but how about how efficient do you think this query is we are having sub queries and joins

Comment: I'm pretty sure about join more efficient then 3 sub-queries.  But best way to know is run on real data. So if you have big enough dataset just run and compare the queries performance

Comment: and I think  coalesce(friends.id, 0) should be coalesce(friends.follower_id, 0) because  and followers.friend_id = p.user_id never gonna be equal to each other